# images write permission

Tags: image

I am using an extension called GTspeed for image optimization; however it is not working because it is asking to give images wrtie permission.
I am using magento and ultimo theme if that will help in asnwering this question.
Thank You!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a third party extension.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to either SSH or FTP into the image storage directory. This is probably in media/ or var/. Make sure the folder and every sub-folder are writable with permissions 0755 or 0777 (if your installation permissions are unorthodox).

Hope that helps. You may need to contact your dev partner if you're not technical.